# Getting GC settings for running JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there a way to get the GC settings for a running JVM?

I'm trying to see what GC algorithm is running SerialGC, ParallelGC, ParallelOldGC, ConcurrentMarkSweepGC, ect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JVM has a nice MBean for that:

```
for(GarbageCollectorMXBean gc : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
   System.out.println(gc.getObjectName());
}
```

You should see MBeans names like "PS Scavenge" or "PS Mark Sweep". Use the following reference to match names with algorithms:

**Copy** (Young) - Copying collector

**ParNew** (Young) - Parallel young generation collector

**PS Scavenge** (Young) - Parallel object scavenger

**MarkSweepCompact** (Old) - Mark and sweep compactor

**ConcurrentMarkSweep** (Old) - Concurrent mark and sweep compactor

**PS MarkSweep** (Old) - Parallel mark and sweep collector

The same information can also be collected with any tool capanle of viewing MBeans: JConsole, JVisualVM, Jprofiler, etc.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have access to the source and I can't recompile.

Comment: You can also view the same MBean information with external tools like JConsole, JVisualVM or JProfiler

Comment: I looked at the MBeans tab under that java.lang.GarbageCollector package but i don't see anything that tells me what is the GC algorithm?

Comment: Pay attention to the MBean names under that tab. For my platform, for example, they are "PS Scavenge" and "PS MarkSweep". See updated answer with name-to-alrorithm reference

Answer (score 3):

You can use jconsole and access some JMX beans of your JVM in its GUI. There you can see details of GC for Tenured or Young parts of JVM Memory. It's just in your jdk/bin folder (HotSpot)

Here is some useful resources:

[Using JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)