# PS MarkSweep is which garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My jdk version is :

```
java version "1.8.0_102"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

this is my test code :

```
List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> beans = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();

    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean bean : beans) {
        System.out.println(bean.getName());
    }
```

result is :

```
PS Scavenge

PS MarkSweep
```

I know PS Scavenge is "Parallel Scavenge" of young generation garbage collector, "PS MarkSweep" is which, is it "Parallel Old"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting GC settings for running JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880914/1362755)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting GC settings for running JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880845/getting-gc-settings-for-running-jvm)

Comment: It's NOT a duplicate, read question carefully

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else finding this question, there is a great overview here:

http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml

To quote the relevant parts for this question:

> ### Young generation collectors
>
> **Copy (enabled with -XX:+UseSerialGC)**
>   the serial copy collector, uses one thread to copy surviving objects from Eden to Survivor spaces
>   and between Survivor spaces until it decides they've been there long
>   enough, at which point it copies them into the old generation.
>
> **PS Scavenge (enabled with -XX:+UseParallelGC)**
>   the parallel scavenge collector, like the Copy collector, but uses multiple threads
>   in parallel and has some knowledge of how the old generation is
>   collected (essentially written to work with the serial and PS old gen
>   collectors).
>
> **ParNew (enabled with -XX:+UseParNewGC)**
>   the parallel copy collector, like the Copy collector, but uses multiple threads in
>   parallel and has an internal 'callback' that allows an old generation
>   collector to operate on the objects it collects (really written to
>   work with the concurrent collector).
>
> **G1 Young Generation (enabled with -XX:+UseG1GC)**
>   the garbage first collector, uses the 'Garbage First' algorithm which splits up
>   the heap into lots of smaller spaces, but these are still separated
>   into Eden and Survivor spaces in the young generation for G1.
>
> ### Old generation collectors
>
> **MarkSweepCompact (enabled with -XX:+UseSerialGC)**
>   the serial mark-sweep collector, the daddy of them all, uses a serial (one
>   thread) full mark-sweep garbage collection algorithm, with optional
>   compaction.
>
> **PS MarkSweep (enabled with -XX:+UseParallelOldGC)**
>   the parallel scavenge mark-sweep collector, parallelised version (i.e. uses
>   multiple threads) of the MarkSweepCompact.
>
> **ConcurrentMarkSweep (enabled with -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC)**
>   the concurrent collector, a garbage collection algorithm that attempts to
>   do most of the garbage collection work in the background without
>   stopping application threads while it works (there are still phases
>   where it has to stop application threads, but these phases are
>   attempted to be kept to a minimum). Note if the concurrent collector
>   fails to keep up with the garbage, it fails over to the serial
>   MarkSweepCompact collector for (just) the next GC.
>
> **G1 Mixed Generation (enabled with -XX:+UseG1GC)**
>   the garbage first collector, uses the 'Garbage First' algorithm which splits up
>   the heap into lots of smaller spaces.