# How to get every jvm setting/parameter from WITH IN running program?

Tags: java, spring, jvm, java-9

Is there a way to get all the setting from which a java program (JVM) is running **from with in the program.**  Yes, I want them from with in the program so I can log them as part of application log.

Here is some useful info - but either they capture this inform from outside the program or only lists specific info from within the program.

1. [Getting the parameters of a running JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317152/getting-the-parameters-of-a-running-jvm) - but this is from outside the program not from within - **i want these settings to be part of application log** for latter reference even after the application is terminated.
2. [Getting GC settings for running JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880845/getting-gc-settings-for-running-jvm) - this is specific to GC details. I want all parameters/setting of JVM from within program.
3. [how to get the min and max heap size settings of a JVM from within a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253976/how-to-get-the-min-and-max-heap-size-settings-of-a-jvm-from-within-a-java-progra) - this is also specific to Memory.
4. [How to read JVM parameters/arguments from within a running Java application](https://alvinalexander.com/java/how-see-jvm-parameters-arguments-from-running-java-application/) - this for **arguments** explicitly passed to the JVM. It's does not capture the other settings not passed to JVM explicitly.

I am fine to use libraries outside of JDK too - like spring etc if they can provide me this info.

Comment: @Brian, please undo the duplication. The Q you pointed to is specific to argument. I am asking for all settings. And did clearly mention this in the Q. You should re-read the Q.

Answer (score 1):

You can get lots of information about the running JVM programmatically from the [ManagementFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) .
Apart from standard MBeans exposing JVM information your other components like appserver, frameworks, application code can expose custom data via JMX and can be accessed.

You can take a look [here](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/blob/b2a139d9febe6ba8e3460da94408a3501caab4eb/javamelody-core/src/main/java/net/bull/javamelody/internal/model/MemoryInformations.java) at an example of how memory related information is extracted from this interface.

Also in another example [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8e2aa5e45ce13388da62386e3cb1dbfa3b242b4b/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/VersionLoggerListener.java) you can see how Tomcat server uses this interface to log the commandline argumnets

```
List<String> args = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
            for (String arg : args) {
                log.info(sm.getString("versionLoggerListener.arg", arg));
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If by JVM settings you mean VM flags, you can get them with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.print(getVMFlags());
}

public static String getVMFlags() throws JMException {
    return (String) ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
            new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
            "vmFlags",
            new Object[]{new String[]{"-all"}},
            new String[]{"[Ljava.lang.String;"});
}
```

Sample output:

```
[Global flags]
     intx ActiveProcessorCount                      = -1          {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizeDecrementScaleFactor          = 4           {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizeMajorGCDecayTimeScale         = 10          {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizePausePolicy                   = 0           {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizePolicyCollectionCostMargin    = 50          {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizePolicyInitializingSteps       = 20          {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizePolicyOutputInterval          = 0           {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight                  = 10          {product}
    uintx AdaptiveSizeThroughPutPolicy              = 0           {product}
    uintx AdaptiveTimeWeight                        = 25          {product}
     bool AdjustConcurrency                         = false       {product}
     bool AggressiveHeap                            = false       {product}
     bool AggressiveOpts                            = false       {product}
     intx AliasLevel                                = 3           {C2 product}
     bool AlignVector                               = false       {C2 product}
...
```

Note, however, this API is not standard. It works only in OpenJDK / HotSpot JVM, and may be changed or even removed in any future release.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check spring boot actuator? This provide lots of OOB metrics for JVM

- Various memory and buffer pool details
- Statistics related to garbage collection
- Threads utilization
- The Number of classes loaded/unloaded

Ref:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.supported